# HTML Email Not Working for Gmail

Tags: html, css

I am using inline css to build this email but somehow it is still not working for Gmail.

```html
<html><body><div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
  <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/6f6b385af54ef142d60ca3b89/images/9e4199e6-b228-426a-9ff4-d38938270c80.jpg" class="background" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;">
  <img src="http://s.mmgo.io/t/4c3" class="timer" style="position: absolute; top: 760px; left: 130px;">
 </div></body></html>
```

In any other inboxes the timer is displayed the way it should be but only in Gmail the timer is displayed below the background image.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Email clients & web clients are very tricky most of them dont really support all the features of HTML. Thats why you mostly make your email layouts with tables :/

Comment: Agreed. If the code isn't from 1920, assume it's too complex for an email.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail does not respond to relative positioning at all. Use width/margin property instead.

Comment: Awesome! Mark it answered/ upvote the answer. All the best @OliviaW :)